# how to create an azure function key in ARM template?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I have been struggling with this one all day, I am trying to create a Function App function key from an ARM template.

So far I have been able to create my function key on the Host level using the following template:

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '/default/PortalFunctionKey')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "PortalFunctionKey"
      }
```

then I found a couple of articles and link showing it is possible via API:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Key-management-API

And I was able to generate it via this API posting to:
`https://{myfunctionapp}.azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/{MyFunctionName}/keys/{NewKeyName}?code={_masterKey}`

But I can't for the sake of me figure out how to do that in my ARM template!
I have tried various combinations of type and name, for example:

```
    {
      "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys",
      "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('appServiceName'), '/{myfunctionName}/PortalFunctionKey')]",
      "properties": {
        "name": "PortalFunctionKey"
      }
```

or /functions/{myfunctionName}/PortalFunctionKey
as suggested in some articles, and i just can't get any to work, can't find much documentation on ARM Microsoft.Web/sites/host/functionKeys either.

Did anyone succeed to create a FUNCTION key (not host) in ARM template? I would gladly hear how you got there :)!

Basically:
[image: Function Keys]

Many thanks in advance,

Emmanuel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is not possible to create a Function level Function key in ARM template at the moment.

I therefore created a feature request you can vote on if you are interested in it:
https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/39789043-create-function-level-keys-for-azure-functions-in

For now though, we are creating function level function keys via a powershell deployment task step. here is how.

add output parameter to your ARM template:

```
  "outputs": {
    "masterKey": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[listkeys(concat(resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('appServiceName')), '/host/default'), '2018-11-01').masterKey]"
    },
    "appServiceName": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[parameters('appServiceName')]"
    },
    "functionKeys": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": [
        {
          "functionName": "myFunctionName",
          "keys": [ "FunctionKeyName1", "FunctionKeyName2" ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Add the following PS script file to your deploy project:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]
    $armOutputString
)

Write-Host $armOutputString
$armOutputObj = $armOutputString | convertfrom-json
Write-Host $armOutputObj

$masterKey = $armOutputObj.masterKey.value
$appServiceName = $armOutputObj.appServiceName.value

$httpHeaders = @{
    "x-functions-key" = $masterKey
}
$contentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"

foreach($function in $armOutputObj.functionKeys.value){

    $retryCount = 5;
    while ($true) {
        try {
            $uriBase = "https://$($appServiceName).azurewebsites.net/admin/functions/$($function.functionName)/keys"
            $existingKeys = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uriBase -Headers $httpHeaders -ContentType $contentType
            break;
        }
        catch {
            if ($_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ -eq 502) {
                if ($retryCount-- -eq 0) {
                    throw;
                }
                else {
                    Write-Output ("Retry" + ": " + $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode + "; attempts=$retryCount")
                    [System.Threading.Thread]::Sleep(1000);
                    continue;
                }
            }
            else {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    foreach ($keyname in $function.keys){
        $keyExists = 0
        foreach($exstingKey in $existingKeys.keys){
            if($exstingKey.name -eq $keyname){
                $keyExists = 1
               Write-Host  "key $($keyname) already exists"
            }
        }

        if($keyExists -eq 0){
            $uri = "$($uriBase)/$($keyname)?code=$($masterKey)";
            Write-Host  "Adding $($keyname) key"
            Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri "$($uriBase)/$($keyname)" -Headers $httpHeaders -ContentType $contentType;
        }
    }
}
```

The script ensures that the key will not be overwritten if it already exists, and will retry if it fails (the function MUST exist and be running for the API to work).

In your "**Azure resource group deployment**" task, under "**Advanced**" set "**Deployment outputs**" to "*armDeployOutput*".

[image]

Add a Powershell task, your script path to the powershell file in your deploy project, and set "**Arguments**" as "*-armOutputString '$(armDeployOutput)'*".

[image]

And that's it.

Comment: It is probably not up to date

Answer (score 1):

This might solve the problem now: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.web/2020-06-01/sites/functions/keys

I was able to create a function key by passing an ARM template resource that looked like this:

```
{
    "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/functions/keys",
    "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
    "name": "{Site Name}/{Function App Name}/{Key Name}",
    "properties": {
        "value": "(optional)-key-value-can-be-passed-here"
    }
}
```

It seems that even if you don't have 'value' in the properties, then you have to at least pass an empty properties object.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem , you could refer to this github issue. [First issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/1007) and [second issue](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3994), these issues all have the problem about how to get the function key in the ARM template.

For now the sample to get the key value as the below shows:

```
"properties": {
        "contentType": "text/plain",
        "value": "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionAppId'), '/host/default/'),'2016-08-01').functionKeys.default]"
        }
```

or with below to get the key object.

```
"functionkeys": {
            "type": "object",
            "value": "[listkeys(concat(variables('functionAppId'), '/host/default'), '2018-11-01')]"                                                                                }
    }
```

You could have a try, hope this could help you.

Comment: Thanks George, unfortunately the retrieval of a key is not the issue here, this works fine, the creation of it via ARM template is my issue, I did refer to the second link you provided to figure out how to create the function key from the web API, and i can create a host/default key from my ARM template. A Function level key is still a mystery though.

Comment: Did you means `masterKey`, from the `POST api/sites/{name}[/slots/{slot}]/host/default/listkeys` API response,suppose you could change `functionKeys.default` to `masterKey` to get the master key.

Comment: Not really, i edited the original question and added a picture there to make it clearer. I can currently add a key in the "Host Keys (All functions)"  section via ARM template. 
I want to be able to do the same for the Function specific key section (via ARM template).